# MySQL Error: Unknown system variable CHARACTER_SET

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am using CHARACTER_SET utf8 in sql execution part and i got an error, `MySQL Error: Unknown system variable CHARACTER_SET`

Here is the code,

```
 $this->runQuery('execute','SET CHARACTER_SET utf8'); // error getting this line.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `CHARACTER_SET` variable, use `CHARACTER SET` instead -

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set character using 
SET NAMES 'utf8';

for more info refer
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-syntax.html